# NuGet.Config is not valid XML. Path '/Users/username/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config' on MacOS

Tags: c#, macos, nuget

I am trying to just run a `dotnet` backend on my MacBook Pro M1. I was instructed to provide a token id and key to the `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` here:

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
  <fwspec>
    <add key="Username" value="token-value" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{TOKEN}" />
  </fwspec>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

I am then instructed to run a `dotnet restore`, but I get the following error:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/dotnet/7.0.100/libexec/sdk/7.0.100/NuGet.targets(676,5): error: NuGet.Config is not a valid XML. Path: '/Users/{username}/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your NuGet.Config file matches the schema to also include the top-level `<configuration>` element. You can start bootstrapping a new one using `dotnet new nugetconfig`.

In your case this should be (`...` being other possible elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <fwspec>
      <add key="Username" value="token-value" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="{TOKEN}" />
    </fwspec>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```